# Memory leaks in C?

Tags: c

I'm currently learning to program in C. In one of the tasks in my assignment, I have to make a histogram (drawn by basic console output, like this: http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/448/histogram.jpg) to measure the number of characters in a text file (standard for this assignment is 1.3 MB). I did make a function like this:

```
int *yAxisAverageMethod(int average, int max, int min)
{
    int *yAxis;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        *(yAxis+i)=0;
    }
/*
    int length=sizeof(data)/sizeof(int);
*/
    int lower_half_interval=average/10;
    int upper_half_interval=(max-average)/10;
    int current_y_value=min;
        for (i=0;i<11;i++)
        {
            if (i==10){
                *(yAxis+10)=average;
                break;
            }
            *(yAxis+i)=current_y_value;
            current_y_value+=lower_half_interval;            
        }
    current_y_value+=average+upper_half_interval;
    printf("Current y value:%d\n",current_y_value);
    printf("Current max value:%d\n",max);
        for (i=11;i<20;i++)
        {
                *(yAxis+i)=current_y_value;
                current_y_value+=upper_half_interval;
        }

    return yAxis;
}
```

In this function, I intend to return an array of 20 integers, in order to make a y axis. I find the average of all characters, then used 20 lines of the console to display it. The lower 10 lines are used to display the lower than average values of the total amount of characters, and 10 lines are used to display the upper part. Each step in the y axis of the lower half is calculated by (average - min)/10, and each step in the y axis of the upper part is calculated by (max - average)/10. This is my method to draw the histogram, because I want to display the variants between values.

In the main method, I have this function call:

```
int *yAxis;
yAxis=yAxisAverageMethod(average,max,min);
```

I got a segmentation fault when I ran the function. In netbean GCC++ compiler, it works fine. Howerver, when I ran it on the university machines (which I have to compile it on command line and edit in Vi), I got the error. I guess it is because Netbean has its own memory manager? I don't understand.

Edited: I will ask about merge sort in anothe question.

Comment: split the merge sort part into another question or it will just get to confusing

Comment: Since you're learning, a stylistic comment: use a decent editor that knows how to indent code for you. The way your `for` loops are indented is pretty jarring to read.

Comment: No, Netbeans doesn't provide you with a Memory Manager. But do you really need those function pointers? If yes, should at least change the function declaration in the top, "int *yAxisAverageMethod(...)" is very unusual syntax. But to find memory leaks you could check out valgrind (memcheck). It's anyways a good idea to become comfortable with valgrind if you program with C/C++... ;-)

Comment: So what's the question? You probably won't find people who are willing to debug this much code for you on StackOverflow. Try reducing your code sample to the minimum possible which still generates an error. You can also look at other mergesort implementations out there to see how they do it. Brian Kernighan has noted how frequently experienced coders can muck up an implementation of a binary search; merge sort is slightly harder.

Comment: Thanks to Tim with the simple fix: int *yAxis = malloc(sizeof(int) * 20); . I don't know about malloc. I get used to program in Java, since it was my starting language and I did programming with it arround for quite long, so program in C is completely awkward to me.

Comment: I also don't get it, why many people and my lecturers suggest me to use VI to become a good programmer. What's so good with a age old editor like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*yAxis is a wild pointer. You never allocate memory for the int array you want to use.

```
int *yAxis = malloc(sizeof(int) * 20);
```

Comment: Extra thanks! It works! Also, I still need to make it work on merge sort.

Comment: I still don't understand why my netbean compiler can run but my university's machine can't.

Comment: That's easy - it depends on the operating system, different systems handle memory in different ways, and (probably) not on the compiler alone.  In all compilers you had a pointer that was pointing to an undefined location, and you were writing there.  If that location happened to be valid memory then many OSs would simply allow you to write there, overwriting whatever was there.  This is a common cause of very nasty bugs.  A system with protected memory would throw an exception as it would see you have no business writing there.  In C you have to deal with these low level things...

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to nothing.

Where inside the function do you tell the computer to reserve some memory for *yAxis?

Answer (score 0):

yAxis is a point, and you did not initialize it. it will point to unknown space what depends on the compiler. you should apply some memory for it firstly.

`yAxis = malloc(sizeof(int)*20);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to free() it in the caller.